# SwipeRevealLayout hide dragged part during recyclerview scrolling

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I used [this](https://github.com/chthai64/SwipeRevealLayout/blob/master/swipe-reveal-layout/src/main/java/com/chauthai/swipereveallayout/SwipeRevealLayout.java) SwipeRevealLayout and noticed very strange behavior. Let see the situation: I have swiped RV item and then without closing opened part start scrolling my list and I noticed that some items below opened item also become swiped. I can't understand why does it happen. So, I decided to close all items at `onBindViewHolder` when my item is on the stage of creating. But I can't get access to closing function of this helper class. How I can solve this problem?

Comment: You have to handle this case using If else condition. Ex: If swipe==true for a item, the do nothing, else  if swipe is false, force the view to close the swipe.

Comment: I understand, but how I can get to know when view is swiped?

Comment: isOpened(), isClosed(): check if the layout is fully opened or closed.
viewBinderHelper.setOpenOnlyOne(boolean openOnlyOne): If openOnlyOne is set to true, you can only open one row at a time.

viewBinderHelper.openLayout(String id): Open a layout. id is the id of the data object which is bind to the layout.

viewBinderHelper.closeLayout(String id): Close a layout. id is the id of the data object which is bind to the layout.

Answer (score 2):

These methods can help you...

`isOpened(), isClosed()`: check if the layout is fully opened or closed.
viewBinderHelper.setOpenOnlyOne(boolean openOnlyOne): If openOnlyOne is set to true, you can only open one row at a time.

`viewBinderHelper.openLayout(String id)`: Open a layout. id is the id of the data object which is bind to the layout.

`viewBinderHelper.closeLayout(String id)`: Close a layout. id is the id of the data object which is bind to the layout.

Comment: `viewBinderHelper` where I have to get this variable?

Comment: and your method can be used inside `onBindViewHolder`?? I can't understand how to use your solution for my project :(

Comment: you have `holder.swipeRevealLayout` this right ? call those fucntions on it

Comment: `holder.swipeRevealLayout` this view as I understand is took from id of item layout? right now I don't have it, but when I created it I still can't see your functions

Comment: I used this one for my list - https://github.com/MarkOSullivan94/SwipeRevealLayoutExample/tree/master/app/src/main/java/me/markosullivan/swiperevealactionbuttons

Comment: I cant see there, that you are using SwipeRevealLayout in the adapter

Comment: in my adapter I only use textviews and some other views which contains the main layout, maybe I have to add some classes?